# Mix View and ViewSet in a browsable api_root

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a [browsable API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/):

```
restaurant_router = DefaultRouter()
restaurant_router.register(r'rooms', RoomsViewSet)
restaurant_router.register(r'printers', PrintersViewSet)
restaurant_router.register(r'shifts', ShiftsViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', api_root),
    url(r'^restaurant/$',
        RestaurantView.as_view(),
        name='api_restaurants_restaurant'),
    url(r'^restaurant/', include(restaurant_router.urls)),
)
```

In the `api_root` I can link to the named route:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'restaurant': reverse('api_restaurants_restaurant', request=request, format=format),
    })
```

Or I can use the browsable API generated by the `DefaultRouter`, as explained in the documentation:

> The DefaultRouter class we're using also automatically creates the API
>   root view for us, so we can now delete the api_root method from our
>   views module.

What do I do if I want to mix `ViewSet`s and normal Views, and show everything in the same API root? The `DefaultRouter` is only listing the `ViewSet`s it controls.

Comment: What do you mean by `mixing viewsets and normal views`. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @mariodev: I want to have a browsable API view (browse tree automatically generated), where some URLs are generated from a viewset, and some from normal views. This is working when you have a DefaultRouter with ViewSets, but as soon as you start adding url_patterns derived from Views (not ViewSets), it breaks down.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your views as ViewSets with only one method.
So you can register it in router and it will be in one space with ViewSets.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: If you are going to work with Django-rest-framework be ready for reading source code and documentation. It helps a lot. I can't give you the code because it depends on your view code. Try examples available by link mentioned above and you'll be able to modify your code properly.

Comment: The code will look like one in knite comment, but code from other_forms_view should be written inside RoomsViewSet.list method. Or other method - it depends on your view code.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't look like there's a simple way to do that using the DefaultRouter, you'd have to build your own router. If it's any consolation the DefaultRouter's logic for generating the APIRoot view is fairly simple and you could probably easily roll your own, similar router based on the DefaultRouter class (e.g. Modify the ApiRoot class implementation to fetch additional URLs to include, you can do this any number of ways e.g. pass them into your Router's constructor):

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/86470b7813d891890241149928d4679a3d2c92f6/rest_framework/routers.py#L263

Answer (score -1):

From http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/:

> A ViewSet class is simply a type of class-based View, that does not provide any method handlers such as .get() or .post(), and instead provides actions such as .list() and .create()

Which means we can extend your ViewSets:

```
def other_rooms_view(request):
    return Response(...)


class RoomsViewSet(ViewSet):
    ...

    def list(self, request):
        return other_rooms_view(request)

restaurant_router = DefaultRouter()
restaurant_router.register(r'rooms', RoomsViewSet)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it could be because your example is not mixing Views and ViewSets, which is what my question is about. I *already* know how to generated a browsable API with only ViewSets (it is indeed in the guide, as you correctly point out). How do you add Views and keep the automatic browse tree generation working?